# How to hide a dialog box?

Tags: android, hide, dialog, dismiss

Is there any alternative way to hide a dialogbox other then using "dismiss()" function??

I already know this way of doing it. but I want to know if there is any other possible way without using the dismiss() function.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try with `dialog.cancel();`

Comment: did you already try the .hide()?, i encounter it once but i forgot how can i solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This method can hide the Dialog. I guess this is what you want.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
    dialog.hide();
}
return false;
```

}